# Google API ClientID and HTML in an UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm developing a webapp with HTML and load it into an simple iPhone app with a `UIWebview`.
This part is working perfectly, but I'm using Goo.gl URL Shortener API and the thing is Google API, in order to get a Client ID, need to specify an Authorized JavaScript Origins, but I don't know what I have to enter.

I tried, `"http://localhost"`, it didn't work, the API is not loading.
I tried also with the iOS application type, enter my app bundle ID, and it didn't work neither.

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: Hi, sorry to up this question, but really need help on this...